# How do I implement bitcoin-seeder for an altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, seed

I am creating an altcoin, following a tutorial. The tutor skipped explaining setting up the DNS seeder.

How can I implement this code https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin-seeder ? Currently when I run `./mycoind` (on my local machine) I get connection refused when trying to connect to the seeder defined in `strMainNetDNSSeed`

When I run `./dnsseed` (on my vps) it does not run on port 8333 (actually 9333, I am using https://github.com/pooler/litecoin-seeder/ , a fork of the bitcoin seeder). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps to setting up a DNS seed, so it is next to impossible to determine why your attempt failed without having more knowledge of your setup.

But if you are trying to set up a DNS seed for an alt coin, then I would strongly suggest you use the generic-seeder to prevent having to muck around in the source code.

The generic-seeder is a clone of the original bitcoin-seeder app that aims to make it easy to run a seeder for virtually any blockchain network. The bitcoin-seeder was developed specifically for the bitcoin network only, and configuring it to work with a different blockchain network can be time-consuming and tedious at best. The generic-seeder overcomes this limitation by utilizing a configuration file that holds the data used to connect to a given blockchain, without having to edit the source code, and adds new features and a full setup tutorial as well.

Github repo: https://github.com/team-exor/generic-seeder
Step-by-step setup guide: https://github.com/team-exor/generic-seeder/blob/master/SETUP.md

Full disclosure: I am the author of the generic-seeder.

Answer (score 0):

DNS seeder runs on port 53 It crawls on p2p port of your coind which in your case is 9333.
Click this [link](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/71909/how-to-setup-nameserver-for-dns-seeder) for further instruction.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.